# What would be the possible drawbacks of using class inheritance for config.py?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, configuration, config

I've been trying to come up with the best way to handle configurations in Python projects and I decided to go with creating a `config.py` and just put all the configurations as classes.

However, I found out that:

1. It is good to have some form of "base" configuration if you want to have multiple configurations.
2. Sometimes getting configurations in `dict` comes in handy when you have to put it in some function parameter.

So I create **my own way** of handling configurations with `config.py` by:

1. Inheriting from `BaseConfig` when I create any new configuration like `NewConfig`
2. Inheriting `@classmethod` that returns all the class variables as `dict`.

However, since I created this code from scratch I would like to know if there's any possible side-effect that can later make me regret.

One thing I'm unsure about is whether it is a good idea to inherit class variables at all.

Also, I managed to make `get_dict()` work but I don't know if its mechanics is good and scalable.

Below is my code:

```py
class BaseConfig:
    ROOT_DIR = Path('.').resolve()
    
    print_every = 2000
    epochs = 3
    lr = 1e-5
    batch_size = 1
    loss = "CrossEntropyLoss"
    optim = "SGD"

    @classmethod
    def get_dict(cls):
        if cls is BaseConfig:
            cls_dict = {k:v for k, v in cls.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_') and k != "get_dict"}
        else:
            cls_dict = BaseConfig.get_dict()
            cls_dict.update({k:v for k, v in cls.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_') and k != "get_dict"})
        
        return cls_dict
    

class NewConfig(BaseConfig):
    epochs = 2
    lr = 5e-5
    optim = "Adam"
    dataset = "CIFAR10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done configuration like this for some of my own projects, and I think it works reasonably well. For the most part, I don't think it's a problem inheriting class attributes.

Some disadvantages I can think of include:

- Reusing class attributes from the parent class can be slightly awkward since you have no way of saying "parent class's attribute" from within the child class without stating the parent explicitly. For example, if you want one of your configuration attributes to be a list that child classes can add to, you either need something like this:

  ```py
  class A:
       my_property = ["a"]

   class B(A):
       my_property = A.my_property + ["b"]
  ```

  or this:

  ```py
  class A:
       my_property = ["a"]

  class B(A):
       pass

  B.my_property = B.my_property + ["b"]
  ```

  I don't think either is especially nice, but this may not be such a big problem for you.
- This sort of configuration requires that users know some basic Python. (Of course, depending on the application, this might not be an issue.)
- For some users, including those familiar with Python, this sort of configuration can seem counterintuitive. I know some people find it strange to have to write Python code as a configuration, and even stranger making the configurations into classes.

---

Regarding the `get_dict` implementation—you might be able to simplify it by using `dir`. For example,

```py
@classmethod
def get_dict(cls):
    return {k:getattr(cls,k) for k in dir(cls) if not k.startswith("_") and k != "get_dict"}
```

This should work is any descendant of your `BaseConfig`.

However, there is a problem with this approach. If you want to add more methods or classmethods to any of your classes, `get_dict` will need to be updated accordingly; this is a pain and is error-prone. For omitting methods, you could try something like this.

```py
@classmethod
def get_dict(cls):
    return {k:getattr(cls,k) for k in dir(cls) if not k.startswith("_") and not callable(getattr(cls,k))}
```

I think this should work well unless some of your configuration parameters are functions. In that case, you may have to resort to maintaining a whitelist of of parameters that should be returned by `get_dict`.

Comment: Excellent points! Didn't know you can use `dir` to handle callables. Also, it seems legit that class based inherited configuration approach can be problematic when you have a mutable object as an attribute.